# Where should "Toasts" live in Mobx State Tree?

Tags: mobx, mobx-state-tree

[image: showing a toast]

My async actions tend to look something like this:

```
anAsyncAction: process(function* anAsyncAction() {
    self.isLoading = true;
    const service = getEnv<IMyMarksPageStoreEnv>(self).myService;
    try
    {
        yield service.doSomething();
    }        
    finally
    {
        self.isLoading = false;
    }
}),
```

Then I let the view handle what toasts to show:

```
toaster = Toaster.create({
    position: Position.TOP
});

render() {
    return <button disabled={this.props.store.isLoading} onClick={this.handleButtonClicked}>Do Async Thing</button>
}

handleButtonClicked = () => {
    const store = this.props.store;
    try
    {
        await store.anAsyncAction();
        toaster.show({ message: "Saved!", intent: Intent.SUCCESS });
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        toaster.show({ message: "Whoops an error occured: "+e, intent: Intent.DANGER });
    }
}
```

But im starting to think that the toasts handling should live in the async try-catch of the store and not the view, but then its mixing business logic with view, so im not sure.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'd argue that messages *are* part of the application.
In my app I have an array at root level

```
export default types.model('AppStore', {
  ....
  flashMessages: types.optional(types.array(FlashMessage), []),
})
  .actions((self) => {
    /* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */
    const addFlashMessage = (message) => {
      self.flashMessages.push(FlashMessage.create({
        ...message,
        details: message.details.toString(),
      }));
    };

    function addErrorMessage(text, details = '') {
      addFlashMessage({ type: 'error', text, details });
    }

    function addInfoMessage(text, details = '') {
      addFlashMessage({ type: 'info', text, details });
    }

    function addSuccessMessage(text, details = '') {
      addFlashMessage({ type: 'success', text, details });
    }
```

Then

```
@inject('appStore')
@observer
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const app = this.props.appStore;

    return (
      <BlockUI tag="div" blocking={app.blockUI}>
        <Notifications messages={app.unseenFlashMessages} />
    ...
```

And in a component

```
this.props.appStore.addSuccessMessage(`User ${name} saved`);
```

This will also allow you to implement a 'last 5 messages' sort of thing which might be useful if you've missed a to

Comment: Oh that interesting, thanks. How do you go about removing the unseen flash messages? During your render() ?

Comment: I'm using `material-ui` for this project so my messages are `Snackbar`s that have a callback for `close` with autohide and a callback (Toastr has `toastr.options.onHidden`. In the callback I `message.setSeen(true)`

Comment: I manage this at the root of my mst models as well. My top level model has a property `snackbarStore` which manages opening/closing snackbars. I then have a component that is always present in the application which reads data from `snackbarStore` and displays the messages when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Guess that's not specific to mobx or mobx-state-tree, but I'd probably consider adding a dedicated `NotificationStore` to the picture. `Service` try/catch/finally would be one producer of notifications with a source of `service`, another might be a fetch/xhr wrapper with a source of `transport`. 
It would be up to the business logic to decide how to present/handle those.

Comment: Could you clarify in your answer a little more what you mean by "one producer of notifications" perhaps with reference to my example code?